# Create block in swift

Tags: swift, block

I want to create block in swift which is equivalent of below objective c block

```
  + (void)WSCall:(
       NSMutableDictionary *)dict 
       WSName:(NSString *)name 
       block:(void (^)(NSDictionary *, NSError *))block{
    }
```

Comment: @longpham or maybe  http://goshdarnclosuresyntax.com

Answer (score 0):

That block is equal to the following of Swift

```
(dict: NSDictionary, error: NSError?) -> Void
```

`NSError` has a `?` at the end. It dictates that it's an optional value.

Comment: NSError should be an optional type. NSError?